# How to write a program to run same script using multiple external tools in eclipse

Tags: ruby, eclipse, automation, report, reporting

I write automated tests. We have different environments we run the tests in for different customers that we provide the same services to before they can be pushed to out automated testing servers. To ensure a test is working we need to run the tests using different external tools in eclipse each time and record and report on it passing/failing. To do this we need to click the green play button with the red toolbox and select an external tool individually each time.

I'm looking for a way that I can write a script that will let me specify which external tools to run the test with and then it'll run the test over and over with the different tools and output some kind of report. I'm not familiar with this kind of thing so any kind of direction would be a huge help.

I'm using Eclipse Keplar on Ubuntu 16.04. The test is a ruby script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scheduler of ubuntu system and execute shell script command to trigger automation.